# Recursive function Python

Tags: python, recursion

So I have been working on this small recursive function in Python, and I am getting stomped. Here's what I have so far and what I would like to have:

```
def search_things(things):
    names = []
    for thing in things:
        if not thing.GetBoundaries():
            names.append(thing)
        else:
            names.append(search_things(thing.GetBoundaries()))
    return names
```

All right, in this case an input into this definition (things) would be a list of FilledRegion objects. Each object has its boundaries which is what I am trying to get. A boundary is a CurveLoop enumerable object that contains a list of curves that make up each boundary.

So basically if I wanted to get at the curves themselves i would take a filled region and do this:

```
boundaries = FilledRegion.GetBoundaries()
```

This will return a list of CurveLoop objects. Each CurveLoop contains a list of curves.

```
for loop in boundaries:
    for curve in loop:
        curves.append(curve)
```

This would get me the curve that I want. Is there a way to modify that original function slightly? Right now since the GetBoundries() returns a list of CurveLoop objects and not the curves themselves I am getting an error that CurveLoop doesnt have the attribute GetBoundaries. How can i return a list of curves themselves where they are arranged as sublists for each filledregion?

So I went in a little bit different direction. I couldnt get it all wrapped into one definition so I created a few:

```
def process_list(_func, _list):
    return map( lambda x: process_list(_func, x) if type(x)==list else _func(x), _list )

def ToDSType(item):
    curves = []
    for i in item:
        curves.append(i.ToProtoType())
    return curves

curves = []
for i in collector:
    curves.append(process_list(ToDSType, i.GetBoundaries()))
```

Is there a way to combine these methodologies? I guess its an abstract question since you cannot test any of this code, but syntax wise. 
1. "i" in the collector is a filled region object
2. GetBoundaries() returns a list of CurveLoop object which are enumerable (List) of curves so i can iterate them like a list. thats what I am doing in the ToDSType method.

Comment: Could you please also add at least the skeleton of the other classes involved (Curve, CurveLoop, Boundary, ...?) So it is a little abstract.

Comment: Its very difficult to read and understand the question without proper definition of the classes/structures. I think posting of at least a stack trace of error would help. Also, I was able to spot a problem; your logic is wrong here: "if not getBoundaries: then names.append(thing) else names.append(EntireListOfThingsThruRecursion)". It should instead be: `else: names = names + search_things(things.getBoundaries())`

Comment: What you describe here looks that way, without knowing the other classes: You get the wrong objects and thing.GetBoundaries() does not work --> your for loop "for thing in things" is not right. You might consider, that "things" (could you change the name "thing" is just to broad!) has a special method that creates an iterator for Curves.

Comment: Minimal example please.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say the question is too much abstract for me, but it looks like a standard tree traversal. I would recommend to read a [Python Algorithms](http://www.apress.com/9781430232377/), Traversal: The Skeleton Key of Algorithmics (chapter 5 ). There are a lot a good examples with explanations.

```
Listing 5-2. Finding Connected Components
-----------------------------------------
def components(G):                  # The connected components
    comp = []               
    seen = set()                    # Nodes we've already seen
    for u in G:                     # Try every starting point
        if u in seen: continue      # Seen? Ignore it
        C = walk(G, u)              # Traverse component
        seen.update(C)              # Add keys of C to seen
        comp.append(C)              # Collect the components
    return comp
```

---

Sorry for incomplete answer, have no reputation to add comment.